# Customer and display file pdf xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pdf.js

I am working with Xamarin form template. Currently I want to display the pdf file on the desktop of the application. I use the pdfjs library and it meets my viewing needs. but now i want to edit it to hide developer bar tools and show me only the contents of the file, but i don't know how to

Comment: "ddiweuf" - what does this mean?  pdf.js is open source, you can modify the source to remove elements you don't want to display

Comment: @Jason - I tried to open the js file for editing but it has too much in it. but I don't know much about javascript